# Xamarin ListView Issue

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am beginer on Xamarin. What did I do wrong here. I am trying to add Conext Menu to ListView and compiler is not happy with this.

```
<ListView x:Name="VehicleList">   
<ListView.ItemTemplate> 
<DataTemplate> 
    <ImageCell
            ImageSource="152x152@1x.png"
            Text="{Binding Title}"
            Detail="{Binding SubTitle}" 
            TextColor="#f35e20"
            DetailColor="#503026" />

        <!--  adding this caused error           
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                Text="Archive" 
                IsDestructive="True" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
        </ViewCell>
        -->     

</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>  
</ListView>
```

Comment: you can't have multiple types of cells in a template - just one

Comment: Ah I suspect that so, can I add multiple template in a ListView? I tried but got other error

Comment: no, every item in the list uses the same template.  It might be more helpful if you explained what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I would like to have standard grid with  small image in first column, second column have Title and SubTitle, third column with context menu/wipe delete type. I can achieve this with ViewCell and multi layer of Stacks, but I want to see if It can be done in a cleaner manner & less code way. Thanks!

Comment: no, using a ViewCell with a layout is the right way to go

Comment: Got it. Thanks Jason!

Comment: "no, every item in the list uses the same template". If you are trying to say, that listviews can only display one item template, that's wrong. You can feed a listview different item templates with a template selector: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/

Answer (score 0):

You are defining two viewcells in one data template. this is not possible!

You should create a DataTemplateSelector and declare the ViewCells in separate classes. Then you can make the selector choose a viewcell based on the logic implemented in the DataTemplateSelector. The xamarin documentation has a nice explanation: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector/